# Executing a javascript function on a remote page from browser

Tags: javascript, browser

Is it possible for a visitor to a page to run an arbitrary function specified in the javascript for that page from their browser?

For a simple example, if the page has a function to hide a particular element when a button is clicked, can a visitor trigger that function and hide the element without clicking the button, but by calling the function directly somehow?

Comment: It is possible through Chrome's console (most browsers have one). The user can type any function available from the global `window`, and such will be executed. (If you are concerned security-wise).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, the user has full control of the DOM. However, it is possible to reduce what can be accessed by using closures. For instance, if I have:

```
(function() {
    var myvar = "can't touch me!";
    // do stuff with myvar
})();
```

Then there is no way for the user to get at or change the string. Similarly for functions, unless you make them global variables (or attach them to the `window` object). Any property attached to the DOM is accessible too, such as the `onclick` attribute of elements. However if you use the `addEventListener` method then I don't think there's any way to find it.

Overall, the browser can't be trusted.

Comment: I do have a php/AngularJS HTML WebPage loaded in an iOS WKWebView in my iOS app. This page has a UI button that copies some text from this page into the iOS clipboard. Can I programmatically trigger this button from my App code in order to get to the provided text without having to press this copy-to-clipboard button on the HTML page itself? With Javascript or even a native iOS API? Thanks for considering to help... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I believe security precautions prevent this generally.

You could use the debugging console. In Chrome, open the **developer tools**, open **console**, and type commands.

Answer (score -3):

If you're using jQuery, you can do

```
$('#id').click();
```

That's the easiest way to do it I think

Comment: Well, we all make mistakes.  Besides, wouldn't that be the same as writing out `function () {do this}` and calling that?  You have to call a function somehow so, either writing it out or "clicking" shouldn't make too much of a difference.

Comment: No? Your question doesn't make sense to me... And yes we do make mistakes, but I at least try to read all of the question instead of just jumping out with a line of jQuery. jQuery is not the answer to everything. 42 is.

Comment: My point was that if the person wants to call a function, I was replying with what I thought would be the best way of calling it.  The function of "click" had already been created, so why create an additional function?  Thank you for your insight Zaphod Beeblebrox

Comment: Just don't make assumptions okay, cuz if you do, I'll rip your spleen out through your throat. :p The OP wants to know whether a user can access functions or variables in any way, which has nothing to do with the developer calling a function.